# How to start Cypress test, Vue front-end, and back-end in one go?

Tags: vue.js, e2e-testing, cypress

I want to set-up E2E tests with Cypress on a Vue.js application. When I start the Cypress test, it warns me that the Vue application (on localhost:8080) is not running, which suprised me a bit at first. As I thought that the Vue application would be started automatically (automagically? ;) with the start of the Cypress tests. But - as it turns out - it does not do this.

What I would like to do now, is to create a test script which will start the Cypress tests, the Vue.js front-end application, and the back-end Node.Js/Express application, in unison.
(The front- and back-end application aren't very big at the moment, so starting them should not take that long. When they get bigger, I will most likely add stubs for the back-end calls.)

However, I cannot find out how to do this! I could start them by hand, but that seems quite cumbersome. And I cannot imagine that this could not be done with the help of some scripting or other code or configuration.

From what I've gathered, I think I need to create some kind of Webpack script to make this happen, but that is all I can find out (I have next to no Webpack experience, which doesn't help either...).
How can i create a (shell?) script to accomplish this?

Comment: simple start-up script in python? If you tried paste it into the question and possible errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to check the Cypress documentation - https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/introduction#Boot-your-server

Here is the excerpt from the content,

Many people approach this situation by running a command like the following:

```
npm start & cypress run // Do not do this
```

The problem is - what happens if your server takes time to boot? There is no guarantee that when the next command runs (`cypress run`) that your web server is up and available. So your Cypress test may start and try to visit your local server before it is ready to be visited.

**Solution**

Luckily, there are some solutions for this. Instead of introducing arbitrary waits (like sleep 20) you can use a better option.

[wait-on](https://github.com/jeffbski/wait-on) module

Using the wait-on module, you can block the `cypress run` command from executing until your server has booted.

```
npm start & wait-on http://localhost:8080

cypress run
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip! I had looked all over the Cypress site, but apparently managed to miss this part...

Comment: Tried to edit your question because your link is broken, but S.O. gave me an error saying "too many edits going on" haha.
Here is the correct LINK: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/introduction#Boot-your-server